# HTTP URLRequest in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, httprequest

Im trying to make a simple HTTP URLReqest in Adobe Flex, heres the code roughly:

```
var requestSender:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlRequest :URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8888");
var msg:String = "data=blah";

urlRequest.data = msg;
urlRequest.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

**This produces something close to:**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Referer: app:/PersonSearch.swf
Accept: text/xml, application/xml, application/xhtml+xml, ...
x-flash-version: 10,1,85,3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 102
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; en-US) ...
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive

data=blah
```

**What I really want is:**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection:close
Via:MDS_777
Accept:*/ *
Host:localhost:8888
Content-Length:104

data=blah
```

Anyone know how I remove the fields like *Accept-Encoding*, add fields like "Via" and set *Connection to "close"*?

Also how do we get the responce from the HTTP request?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve my doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash Player doesn't allow you to change the *Accept-Encoding* or *Via* headers through ActionScript. If you try do that you will get a message like this one:

> Error #2096: The HTTP request header
>   Accept-Encoding cannot be set via
>   ActionScript.

If you are using URL variables you can try to simplify your code by doing this:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.data = "blah"; //same as doing data=blah
variables.data2 = "blah2"; //same as doing data2=blah2

var requestSender:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8888");
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = variables;
```

To get the response you will have to listen for the `Event.COMPLETE` on the "requestSender":

```
requestSender.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    // do something with requestSender.data (or URLLoader(event.target).data)
}
```